# Getting STDOUT and STDERR from subprocess.Popen synchronously

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm looking to write some simple utilities that call native executables/scripts. I'm already fairly familiar with using `subprocess.Popen` to open processes, but I don't understand how to effectively get access to the subprocess' STDOUT and STDERR synchronously in Python. I understand that I can pass it a `file`-like object and it'll work fine, but how exactly do I do that? I don't want to write it to an actual filesystem file, so how do I do this? Do I need the `mmap.mmap()` memory file API?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class CoolReader():

    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target 

    def write(self, output):
        self.target.append({timestamp: time.time(), value: output})

stdoutLines = []
stderrLines = []

stdoutReader = CoolReader(stdoutLines)
stderrReader = CoolReader(stderrLines)

subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout=stdoutReader, stderr=stderrReader)
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I'd basically like to have a listener be fired every time a line is written to STDOUT or STDERR to synchronously write file lines to an array or something. How can I/should I do this?

Comment: Which OS? On Unix you have [`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#module-select) for File Descriptors, on Windows you have to use Threads with Queues.

Comment: you could probably do `p=subprocess.Popen("ls",stdout=subprocess.PIPE); p.stdout.readline(); p.stdout.readline()`  Of course, to prevent this from blocking, you'd need to read the lines on a separate thread.

Comment: @mgilson I'd like to not have to run multiple threads because I'd like to have to avoid dealing with concurrency. Would my example above work similarly?

Comment: @TKKocheran -- I tried your example and it doesn't work.  The reason (I think) is because subprocess works with low level file handles as opposed to high level file objects that we're used to in the python API.